# Flow can't access a custom setting (Check Syntax fails)

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm knee deep in my migration to flow from workflow and triggers and I've decided to put in a custom setting killswitch so I can turn the flows on and off like I do on triggers. I built my flow settings custom setting and now I'm in a record triggered flow.

My problem is that when I start to adjust the entry conditions on the flow. I make a formula condition, search for the setting, click on it, and add it. If I check syntax I get an error it doesn't exist.

> Error: Field does not exist. Check spelling.

Has anyone ever seen this before? Am I doing this wrong?

[image]

Comment: just try saving the flow and ignore the check syntax button

Comment: It let me save, it's strange the check syntax doesn't like it. I tried older custom settings and got the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002LF0TQAW) and scheduled for fixing Spring 23

The workaround is to not click the Check Syntax button and just save the flow - it will save (and execute) successfully